# Is 2-bromobutane chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

My textbook says 2-bromobutane is chiral, but it look like it will form superimposition mirror image

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a molecule to be chiral it must have **non-superimposable mirror images**.  Here is a drawing of the two mirror images for 2-bromobutane.

[image]

The chiral carbon atom is denoted by an asterisk.  In the case of 2-bromobutane there are 4 different substituents attached to it. The molecule is chiral, you can't pick up one of the mirror images and superimpose it on the other.

Note to think about:

- 4 different substituents may make an atom chiral, but the molecule as a whole may still be achiral

For example meso compounds

[image]

[image source](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Chirality/Meso_Compounds)

- some molecules without 4 different substituents attached to an atom may still be chiral .

For example, compounds with [axial chirality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_chirality) such as chiral allenes (1,3-dimethylallene), chiral biphenyls, chiral helicenes, etc.

[image]

[image source](http://www.med-chemistry.com/2014/09/chiral-compounds-without-asymmetric.html)

[image]

[image source](http://www.chemhelper.com/unusualchirality.html)

[image]

[image source](http://thelab.photophysics.com/circular-dichroism/publications-alert-latest-circular-dichroism-research-2/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is chiral because there are 4 different groups on the second carbon, H, Br, methyl and ethyl.

Maybe you are looking at a planar depiction.