# Does a non-chiral substrate (2-bromo-2-methylpropane) also form two products via an SN1 mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, chirality, nucleophilic-substitution

If I have an alkyl halide, in which its tertiary carbon is non-chiral (for example 2-bromobutane), which reacts via an S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism does it also produce 2 products?

I am asking because I know that the carbocation intermediate's plane of symmetry allows the nucleophile to attack equally well from either side and thus the product is a racemic mixture of enantiomers.  Is this also the case for a non-chiral substrate?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: The formation of the product will happen along both pathways, but since the product is as achiral as the reactant, you won't find different products, and you can't tell.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here; 2-bromobutane is undoubtedly chiral ([we even have a question on it](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27153/16683)). If you mean something like 2-bromopropane, or 3-bromopentane, then Martin's comment is spot on.

Comment: You are asking about a non-chiral substrate, but the example you chose is chiral. Which case are you asking about? Could you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant 2-bromo-2-methylpropane. I edited it out.
I must have confused it with another substrate I was looking at.